# struts 2 s:date tag with value from variable in request with it's name in request

Tags: date, struts2, tags

I have a problem in my web app with struts 2 and a date value. I've got a form and inside it an s:textfield that shows a date value. I read this value from request, and the problem is that the name of that value is in other variable.

**The Action** I'm calling does this:

```
...   
public String execute(){ return SUCCESS;}

public MyObject getObject1(){   
  MyObject result = new MyObject();  
  result.setDate(new java.util.Date());  
  return result;  
}  
...
```

On SUCCESS it goes to my form.

The code in **my form** (what I was wondering to write) is:

```
<s:form action="save">
  <s:set name="objName" value="object1"></s:set>  
  <jsp:include page="../includedform.jsp"></jsp:include>  
</s:form>
```

And in the **"includedform.jsp"** there is:

```
<s:textfield name="%{objName}.date" label="Date" >  
  <s:param name="value">  
    <s:date name="%{%{objName}.date}" format="dd/MM/yyyy" />  
  </s:param>  
</s:textfield>
```

The syntax: 
`%{%{objName}.anagrafica.dataNascita}`
doesn't work (it shows nothing, obviously). **So i'll need something like this but working :)**

Other tags s:textfield inside "includedform.jsp" (ommited in the code bellow for simplicity) without date fields are working, because I am using only the name attribute and struts looks automatically for the value. This is the code I use for these textfields:

```
<s:textfield name="%{objName}.name" label="Name"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is very confusing and you need to rephrase to make it more clear and readable.
i am not sure why you are doing this

```
<s:textfield name="%{objName}.date" label="Date" >
```

while this can be done like

```
<s:textfield name="objName.date" label="Date" > OR 
<s:textfield name="%{objName.date}" label="Date" >
```

when you write `objName.date` OGNL assume that you have a bean in your action class namely `objName` and this bean has property namely `date`, s ultimately this will get converted to

`getObjName().getDate()` by ONGL

On a similar fashion `<s:date name="%{%{objName}.date}" format="dd/MM/yyyy" />` datee tag works
For more details please refer to the official doc

- [Struts2 Date tag](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/date.html)

Comment: I do not have a bean called objName with a property called date. I have a String called objName with the name of the bean that contains the date property.

Comment: i am all confused now? can you be more clear what and how you setting that bean and what exactly u r doing

Comment: Did you mean `"%{%{objName}.date}"` *doesn't* work? There's nothing in OGNL to handle recursive expressions, unless it was added quite recently.

Comment: I know it doesn't work. I hope someone knows a way to do this.

The question is clear now?

Comment: @user1175169:not sure why you want to do like this while the object can be fetched in a most easiest way as described in post and moreover as told recursive expressions and not allowed in OGNL

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution which i tried and it worked :)
1)Keep the column in which you want to store date in database's table in "DATE" data type only.
 2)Use only Textfield tag in JSP page.Dont use Date tag.
**Note:Make sure that you make user input date in YYYY-MM-DD format only by placing a placeholder in textfield tag !**
3)Keep the variable for accessing that field of string type only.Dont use DATE data type.
4)Now run Query: **Select DATE_FORMAT(datecolumnname,'%d/%m%/Y') as date_two from tablename;** and you will get date from that columnin dd/mm/yyyy format even if it is stored in YYYY-MM-DD format in table .
5)And you can also compare your datecolumn's data with curdate() and related functions as well and it works :) .
6)Like i used query: **Select id,name,DATE_FORMAT(datecolumnname,'%d/%m/%Y') as datecolumn2 from tablename where datecolumnname >= curdate();**